# excel mapping to match columns

Tags: excel, dictionary, shortcut

I have two huge columns in excel. One of them is 8400 lines and another one is 12.5k lines. I need to map the column names so that the old and new schema are matching in another column. VLookUp is not an option because I don't want to return a boolean.

for example, sub_churn_comp_segment (6503) --> sub_churn_comp_segment (11076). Is there any smart way of doing this rather than going through all the 12,000 lines ?

Your inputs are appreciated.

Comment: bonus for thinking 12.5K is **huge**. That's cute!